# I am shia but i take the ghusl that mohammed (saw) took, is that fine or do i need to take the shia way of taking ghusl?

Tags: ghusl

I am a shia but for a while now i take the sunni’s way of taking ghusl, I am not sure if I am doing it correct so please respond to this question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference between the two methods.

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds offensive , but a Shi'a AFAIK is a Muslim why should your ghusl be different than that of our prophet? Isn't the prophet the first instance to follow when it comes to the rulings of Islam?

Answer (score -2):

If you ask me, it shouldn't matter. A Muslim is a Muslim. And we should all try to be more like the Prophet Muhammad (Peace be upon him).

Comment: Thank you brother and you are very correct. May Allah bless you.

Comment: You are very welcome :)